# send named arrays to PHP via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I need to submit a dynamically created field set via ajax call to a php to insert the data to DB. The list is for product items for a specific supplier. I need to make a ajax call , but dont know how to submit the named arrays in data field.

My HTML:

```
<div class='col-md-2 '><input name="item_number[]" id="item_number" class="form-control" placeholder='item number' /></div>
    <div class='col-md-4 '><input name="description[]" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder='description' /></div>
    <div class='col-md-1 '><input name="quantity[]" id="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder='Quantity' /></div>
    <div class='col-md-2 '><input name="unit_price[]" id="unit_price" class="form-control" placeholder='Unit Price' /></div>
   <div class='col-md-2 '><input name="sales_price[]" id="sales_price" class="form-control" placeholder='Sales Price' /></div>
   <div><button name="add_item" id="add_item" class="btn btn-primary">+</button></div>
```

How can i get the value set posted to my PHP file and then insert them via a for loop

My PHP file is as below:

```
$supplier_selection = $_POST['supplier_id'];
$item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
$array_description = $_POST['description'];
$array_quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$array_unit_price = $_POST['unit_price'];
$array_sale_price = $_POST['sale_price'];

    foreach ($item_id as $key => $value) {
    $check_item_id = "SELECT item_id from products where item_id='" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($item_id [$key]) . "'LIMIT 1";
    $resultset = $mysqli->query($check_item_id);
    if ($resultset->num_rows == 0) {
        //perform insert to table
        $insert_product = "INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `item_id`, `supplier_id`, `description`, `quantity`, `purchase_price`, `retail_price`) "
                . "VALUES (NULL, '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string(item_id) . "','$supplier_selection', '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($array_description[$key]) . "',  '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($array_quantity[$key]) . "', '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($array_unit_price[$key]) . "', '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($array_sale_price[$key]) . "')";
        $insert_item = $mysqli->query($insert_product);

        if (!$insert_item) {
            echo $mysqli->error;
            echo "<script>";
            echo "alert('Error inserting!')";
            echo "</script>";

        } else {
            echo "successfully inserted" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($item_id[$key]) . "";
            echo "<script>";
            echo "alert('Items Added successfully')";
            echo "</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you use jQuery and $.ajax so you can just serialize the form     you need and it will gather all data from the form in proper format:

```
$('#form_id').serialize()
```

You can insert it into the data param into $.ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/your/url/here',
    data: $('#form_id').serialize()
});
```

In the php code it is very stupid to make DB queries in the loop.
I see you are getting data from the HTML form by POST request so there will not be millions of items to loops through.
Here is the more efficient code you may use, kinda 2 times less amoutn of DB queries:

```
<?php
$supplier_selection = $_POST[ 'supplier_id' ];
$item_id = $_POST[ 'item_id' ];
$array_description = $_POST[ 'description' ];
$array_quantity = $_POST[ 'quantity' ];
$array_unit_price = $_POST[ 'unit_price' ];
$array_sale_price = $_POST[ 'sale_price' ];
//get all item IDs received
$all_keys = array_keys( $item_id );
//get all items in DB with item_id in received array
$not_to_insert_sql = "SELECT item_id from products where item_id IN (" . implode( ',', $all_keys ) . ")";
$not_to_insert = $mysqli->query( $not_to_insert_sql );
//need to get only IDs
for ( $i = 0, $c = count( $not_to_insert ); $i < $c; ++$i ) {
    $not_to_insert[] = $not_to_insert[ $i ][ 'item_id' ];
}
//let's get difference between what's in the array and what is already in DB
$to_insert = array_diff( $all_keys, $not_to_insert );
// let's loop only what we need to insert
for ( $i = 0, $c = count( $to_insert ); $i < $c; ++$i ) {
    //perform insert to table
    $insert_product = "INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `item_id`, `supplier_id`, `description`, `quantity`, `purchase_price`, `retail_price`) "
        . "VALUES (NULL, '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string( item_id ) . "','$supplier_selection', '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string( $array_description[ $key ] ) . "',  '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string( $array_quantity[ $key ] ) . "', '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string( $array_unit_price[ $key ] ) . "', '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string( $array_sale_price[ $key ] ) . "')";
    $insert_item = $mysqli->query( $insert_product );

    if ( ! $insert_item ) {
        echo $mysqli->error;
        echo "<script>";
        echo "alert('Error inserting!')";
        echo "</script>";

    }
    else {
        echo "successfully inserted" . $mysqli->real_escape_string( $item_id[ $key ] ) . "";
        echo "<script>";
        echo "alert('Items Added successfully')";
        echo "</script>";
    }
}
```